# How to pass 2 parameters in wps with jiffle in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, geotools, xml, wps, jiffle

I'm trying to send 2 sources to process with jiffle (adding a second input on wps:inputs, in this example both are the same layer so the result should be 0), but when I try to execute a simple task like: dest = src-src1, the result is distinct of zero

I'm not sure if it's possible to do like this, because I didn't find any similar example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>ras:Jiffle</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>coverage</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="image/tiff" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wcs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wcs:GetCoverage service="WCS" version="1.1.1">
            <ows:Identifier>cliente1:chanar_agua</ows:Identifier>
            <wcs:DomainSubset>
              <ows:BoundingBox crs="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#32721">
                <ows:LowerCorner>338900.0 6533020.0</ows:LowerCorner>
                <ows:UpperCorner>356890.0 6542140.0</ows:UpperCorner>
              </ows:BoundingBox>
            </wcs:DomainSubset>
            <wcs:Output format="image/tiff"/>
          </wcs:GetCoverage>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
     <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>coverage</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="image/tiff" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wcs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wcs:GetCoverage service="WCS" version="1.1.1">
            <ows:Identifier>cliente1:chanar_agua</ows:Identifier>
            <wcs:DomainSubset>
              <ows:BoundingBox crs="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#32721">
                <ows:LowerCorner>338900.0 6533020.0</ows:LowerCorner>
                <ows:UpperCorner>356890.0 6542140.0</ows:UpperCorner>
              </ows:BoundingBox>
            </wcs:DomainSubset>
            <wcs:Output format="image/tiff"/>
          </wcs:GetCoverage>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>script</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:LiteralData>dest=src-src1;</wps:LiteralData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="image/tiff">
      <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying optional request to GeoServer, i changed the body of request and the result is that i expected.

```
<wps:Body>
<wcs:GetCoverage xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/2.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/2.0 
http://schemas.opengis.net/wcs/2.0/wcsAll.xsd"
service="WCS" version="2.0.1">\
 <wcs:CoverageId>cliente1__chanar_agua</wcs:CoverageId>
  <wcs:DimensionSlice>
    <wcs:Dimension>time</wcs:Dimension>
    <wcs:SlicePoint>2019-12-05T00:00:00.000Z</wcs:SlicePoint>
   </wcs:DimensionSlice>
  <wcs:format>image/tiff</wcs:format>
 </wcs:GetCoverage>
</wps:Body>
```